# what does deploy command does in aws sagemaker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, autoscaling, amazon-sagemaker

I am curious to know what does the model.deploy command actually does in the background when implemented in aws sagemaker notebook
for eg :
**predictor = sagemaker_model.deploy(initial_instance_count=9,instance_type='ml.c5.xlarge')**

and also at the time of sagemaker endpoint autoscaling what is happening in the background, it is taking to long almost 10 minutes to launch a new-instances, by which most of the requests get dropped or not processed and also getting connection timeout while load testing threw JMeter. Is there any way to fast bootup or golden AMI kind of thing in sagemaker?

are there any other means by which this issue can be solved?

Answer (score 1):

The docs mention what the deploy method does: https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/model.html#sagemaker.model.Model.deploy

You could also take a look at the source code here: https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/master/src/sagemaker/model.py#L377

Essentially the deploy method hosts your model on a SageMaker Endpoint, launching the number of instances using the instance type that you specify. You can then invoke your model using a predictor: https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/predictors.html

For autoscaling, you may want to consider lowering your threshold for scaling out so that the additional instances start to be launched earlier. This page offers some good advice on how to determine the RPS your endpoint can handle. Specifically, you may want to have a lower SAFETY_FACTOR to ensure new instances are provisioned in time to handle your expected traffic.